# How do I properly use the Ruby DelegateClass to wrap YAML::Store?

Tags: ruby, yaml, delegates, wrapper, facade

### Testing Environment

I've tried this in both Ruby 3.0.2 and Ruby 2.73, with similar results. It shouldn't matter for the problem at hand, as I've also tried this under different shells and ruby managers, but this is primarily being tested under:

- fish, version 3.3.1
- chruby: 0.3.9
- chruby-fish: 0.8.2
- macOS 11.6

### Describing the Problem (Code and Errors in Subsequent Sections)

I'm trying to use the poorly (or possibly even undocumented) DelegateClass from the [Delegator](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Delegator.html) class to create a facade for YAML::Store that allows me to read and write arbitrary keys to and from a YAML store. However, I clearly don't understand how to properly delegate to the YAML::Store instance, or to override or extend the functionality in the way that I want.

For simplicity, I wrote my example as a self-executing Ruby file names example.rb, so please scroll to the end to see the actual call to the classes. I'm hoping that my mistake is fairly trivial, but if I'm fundamentally misunderstanding how to actually perform the delegation of CollaboratorWithData#write and ollaboratorWithData#read to MultiWriter, please educate me.

*Note: I know how to solve this problem by simply treating [YAML::Store](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/Store.html) as an object instantiated within my class, or even as a separate object that inherits from YAML::Store (e.g. `class MultiWriter < YAML::Store`) but I'm very much trying to understand how to properly use Forwardable, SimpleDelegator, and Delegate to wrap objects both in the general case and in this particular use case.*

#### Self-Executing Code File (Some Vertical Scrolling Required)

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'delegate'
require 'yaml/store'

module ExampleDelegator
  attr_accessor :yaml_store, :data

  class CollaboratorWithData
    def initialize
      @yaml_store = MultiWriter.new
      @data = {}
    end

    def some_data
      {a: 1, b:2, c: [1, 2, 3]}
    end
  end

  class MultiWriter < DelegateClass(YAML::Store)
    attr_reader :store

    def initialize file_name="store.yml", thread_safe=true
      super
      @store = self
    end

    def write **kwargs
      @store.transaction { kwargs.each { |k, v| @store[k] = v } }
    end

    def read *keys
      @store.transaction(read_only=true) { keys.map { |k| @store[k] } }
    end
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  include ExampleDelegator

  c = CollaboratorWithData.new
  c.data = c.some_data
  c.write(c.data)
end
```

##### Errors When Running File

###### Error in Initializer

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    5: from ./example.rb:40:in `<main>'
    4: from ./example.rb:40:in `new'
    3: from ./example.rb:11:in `initialize'
    2: from ./example.rb:11:in `new'
    1: from ./example.rb:24:in `initialize'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/delegate.rb:71:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
```

Please note that, if you look carefully at the invocation of [YAML::Store#new](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/Store.html#method-c-new), one of the possible signatures *does* take two arguments. I don't understand why it won't allow me to specify thread safety when I can do it in IRB:

```rb
foo = YAML::Store.new 'foo.yml', true
#=> #<Psych::Store:0x00007f9f520f52c8 @opt={}, @filename="foo.yml", @abort=false, @ultra_safe=false, @thread_safe=true, @lock=#<Thread::Mutex:0x00007f9f520f5138>>
```

###### Error in Method Delegation with Modified Initializer

Even if I take out the *thread_safe* argument, I still get NoMethodError from CollaboratorWithData when calling the delegated #write method, which leads me to believe that there are issues with my implementation of delegation beyond the initializer.

```
./example.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
./example.rb:42:in `<main>': undefined method `write' for #<ExampleDelegator::CollaboratorWithData:0x00007ff86e0e15c8> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go over some of your questions regarding delegation:

- **Forwardable**:
  This module when extended allows you to specify specific methods that should be delegated to a designated Object (most often an instance variable) Example:

```
require 'forwardable'
class A 
  attr_reader :obj
  extend Forwardable 
  def_delegator :@obj, :<<
  
  def initialize(val) 
    @obj = val
  end 
end 

a = A.new([])
a << 1
#=> [1]
a.obj 
#=> [1]
```

- **Delegator**: Inheriting from this class allows methods to be delegated to an Object passed via `new`. This Object is internalized upon instantiation using the `__setobj__` method and calls are forwarded via `method_missing`; however the caveat here is that it uses 2 methods that are not defined by default(`__setobj__` and `__getobj__`) and you would need to define them in the inheriting class
- **SimpleDelegator**: Inherits from `Delegator` and shares its personality in most regards; however it predefines the 2 methods previously discussed. Generally inheriting from `SimpleDelegator` is preferred over inheriting directly from the `Delegator` class for its ease of use.
- **DelegateClass**: Is similar to `SimpleDelegator` however it creates a new anonymous class which defines all the instance methods of the class passed in as an argument and then your inheriting class inherits from this anonymous class directly which allows method via inheritance rather than using method_missing for delegation. e.g.

```
class A < Delegator;end
class B < DelegateClass(String);end
A.ancestors 
#=> [A, Delegator, #<Module:0x00007fffcc1cc9c8>, BasicObject]
B.ancestors
#=> [B, #<Class:0x00007fffcc5603c8>, Delegator, #<Module:0x00007fffcc1cc9c8>, BasicObject]
A.instance_methods - Object.instance_methods
#=> [:__getobj__, :__setobj__, :method_missing, :marshal_dump, :marshal_load]
B.instance_methods - Object.instance_methods
#=> Array of all the public the instance methods of String plus the above
```

This is generally preferable when you are expecting the class to be instantiated with a specific type of Object because the Module injection avoids the full inheritance chain traversal that comes in to play with `method_missing`. This does not mean that you cannot instantiate this class with another object (however if you do and that object defines methods not defined in the class argument passed to `DelegateClass` it will fall back to the default `method_missing` behavior)

**Now to your Code**
Your first error is the call to `super`. The `Delegator` expects 1 argument which an instance of the `Object` being delegated to (`YAML::Store` in your case) however you have defined 2 arguments (neither of which represents the object you wish to delegate to) and when you call `super` both these arguments are forwarded on, thus the error.

Removing `thread_safe` works because you now only have a single argument but your delegated object in this case is actually the String `"store.yml"`

For Example the following modification should work (Similar to the example provided in the [Source Code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/lib/delegate.rb#L371)

```
module ExampleDelegator
  class MultiWriter < DelegateClass(YAML::Store)
    attr_reader :store

    def initialize file_name="store.yml", thread_safe=true
      @store = YAML::Store.new(file_name,thread_safe)
      super(@store)
    end
  end
end
```

Your second issue is that you are calling `write` on the `CollaboratorWithData` object which does not define this method and is not otherwise delegating.

While I am not 100% sure what your intent is here as there are some other oddities like `attr_accessor` in the Module body which is then being included in the global space and as it stands I do not see a true reason for a `Delegator` becuase you could just use the Object directly via the `yaml_store` instance variable being set to an instance of `YAML::Store` (as you already mentioned) but you can rewrite your code as follows to use delegation if you wish

```
require 'delegate'
require 'yaml/store'
require 'forwardable'

module ExampleDelegator
  class CollaboratorWithData
    extend Forwardable
    def_delegators :@yaml_store, :read, :write

    attr_reader :yaml_store
    attr_accessor :data
    
    def initialize(file_name="store.yml", thread_safe=true)
      @yaml_store = MultiWriter.new(YAML::Store.new(file_name,thread_safe))
      @data = {}
    end
    
    def some_data
      {a: 1, b:2, c: [1, 2, 3]}
    end
  end

  class MultiWriter < DelegateClass(YAML::Store)
    def write **kwargs
      transaction { kwargs.each { |k, v| @store[k] = v } }
    end
    def read *keys
      transaction(read_only=true) { keys.map { |k| @store[k] } }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I upvoted for the thorough answer, but I need to think my way through it a bit more. You're right that it was probably not an ideal use case; I ended up simply subclassing YAML::Store with the added behavior, which was intended to simplify explicitly calling multiple assignments to the YAML::Store (or PStore, really, since they work almost the same). I *wanted* to delegate #read and #write from CollaboratorWithData, and have the reads and writes handled in MultiWriter, but as you correctly pointed out this was not really the best use case for delegation or forwarding.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs what you are describing is a reasonable use case for `Forwardable` in addition to delegation to create what is essentially a nested Decorator Pattern answer updated accordingly.